# git hub private repo?

Tags: git, github

I have thousands of codes and documents. I want to upload them to the private repo in GIT HUB.

But I am worried that code examples or documents may contain the server name or IP address of production servers.

If I upload a document that contains a server name or IP address or some key in my private repo. Will it get captured by some tools security running in my company? (this security scan runs once in 3 months)

Comment: Don't put secrets in git is the short answer but for posterity's sake at the very least you know it's a private repo with access control management.

Comment: If it's in a private repo, only those with access can access it

Comment: My Question is : if there is any tool which can scan private repo ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you should not check secrets into a repository.  Anything like passwords, tokens, cryptographic keys (except public keys), or any sort of personally identifying information should just not be stored in a repository.  It's very easy for a repository to accidentally get exposed and then leak the secrets.

However, having said that, usually server names and IP addresses are not considered secrets in this way.  For example, if a server uses a publicly trusted TLS certificate, then literally everybody on the Internet can see its name, because it's stored in a public certificate transparency ledger.  Also, there are only so many internal IP address ranges, and everyone knows you're using one of those and can usually guess which one, at that.  Those kinds of things are checked into repositories all the time without problems and aren't usually considered secrets.

However, you should consider what your company's policy is.  If it's a private repo in one of your company's GitHub organizations, then the administrators of that organization can see it and scan it, and if your company has a policy against this, even if it's silly, you should generally follow it.  If it's a personal private repository, then nobody will be able to see it but you and your company's tools won't be able to find it, but be aware that will probably fall afoul of your company's data storage policies.

Also, be aware that Git is not a great storage mechanism for binary document formats like Word documents and PDFs.  It does great with text documents and source code, though.

Comment: My Question is : if there is any tool which can scan private repo ?

Comment: Whose private repo?  Yours or your company's?  If it's your company's, then yes, they can scan it because they own it.  If it's yours, only you and keys and applications you've allowed access can scan it.